# Possible to perform additional regex on a capturing group as part of replacement?

Tags: regex

So it's possible to use modifiers like \L on a capturing group to make it all lower case, e.g. `\L\2`. What if I want to perform an additional replacement on a capturing group as part of the replacement, e.g. replace a letter. So, given:

```
cat sat on the mat
```

regex: `(\w)(at)`

replacement idea: `\1{replace c with b}\2`

desired result:

```
bat sat on the mat
```

**Edit:** I would prefer the solution to not need to access the matching groups as a second step (that's a somewhat obvious solution and doesn't match my criteria above of the "replacement idea" having some kind of indicator in the actual *replacement string itself* that indicates that a further replacement must occur). **If this is not possible** in any flavour of regex, I would like to know this. The language used to solve this does not matter to me, I'm not constricted by language.

Comment: First, what language are you using?

Comment: I am looking for a language agnostic way of doing this, something that will work equally well in Notepad++ or Python. Does this functionality not exist within the typical regex engine?

Comment: regex engines vary greatly between language implementations.

Comment: I'm aware of that but there is a lot of common functionality, or multiple ways of doing the same thing (e.g. $1 vs \1 or different ways of specifying recursive patterns)

Comment: There is nothing called `language agnostic regex`.

Comment: `\L\2` won't make your replacement lowercase. :/

Comment: You won't do this using regex alone....

Answer (score 1):

For Javascript:

```
var replaced = "cat sat on the mat".replace(/(\w)(at)/g, function($0, $1, $2){return $1.replace(/c/g, "b") + $2;})
```

Comment: This is a straightforward solution until OP specifies his programming language. For example, I am aware that in Java one would use `.group()`.

Comment: +1 for lambda replacement (delegate in C#, `preg_replace` in PHP etc)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it in Java.

If you want all `c`'s in all groups to be replaced by `b`, you could use

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "cat sat on the mat with another cat which was fat";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.print(m.group(1).replace('c', 'b') + " ");
    }

}

input : "cat sat on the mat with another cat which was fat";
output : bat sat on the mat with another bat whibh was fat
```

Comment: OP wants to _"replace c with b"_ for captured group 1, not replace whatever equals the first character of it into 'b'. Plus, you'll get an exception when there is no match if you do it like this.

Comment: @Unihedron - replace *any* `c` in any group with `b` ?

Comment: @Unihedron - Edited my answer..Is my understanding of the OP's question, still wrong?

Comment: Looks good. `cat sat on the mat with another cat which was fat` will become `bat sat on the mat with another bat which was fat` since OP's original intention was to replace the character in the first group of `(\w)(at)`, though just now I realized you could have replaced the whole match since group 2 can't have `'c'` in it anyway.